# Spring Boot logback creating and leaving big size .tmp files

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, logback

I found out some problem with logback creating .tmp files.
I did look at all of the previous questions about logback config questions about .tmp files, and I still have a question.

It's not about the logback-config.xml problem.
My config file is working well.

The problem is, my server is a **batch program server**, and the java process is not always running, but runs when my Jenkins scheduler tells it to run.

My logback config has this RollingPolicy

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
   <fileNamePattern>${appLogFilePath}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz</fileNamePattern>
   <maxFileSize>200MB</maxFileSize>
   <maxHistory>5</maxHistory>
   <totalSizeCap>3GB</totalSizeCap>
</rollingPolicy>
```

So it rolls and create .gz file every 200MB or, at 00:00 every day.

But when it starts rolling, my batch java process could end before it's done with compressing.
So it leaves a .tmp file, and imcomplete .gz file.

Is there any good solution for this problem?

This is my idea to a possible solution

1. Create a shell script file to delete every *.tmp files every 5 days.

Because my log files are not that important,  I thought it could be okay to delete the *.tmp files.

Please share some good ideas to solve this problem.

Thank you